# How to create sidebar from "scratch"?

Tags: widgets, templates, sidebar, gallery, register-sidebar

I want to create a section on my website which will contain information about different locations, this section has tabs width different information:

[image: content-image]

My idea was to register a sidebar and then use a custom template and just call `get_sidebar('location');` where necessary.

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'          => 'Ubicación',
    'id'            => 'location',
    'description'   => 'Agregar galerías de ubicaciones',
));
```

I want that every widget on my "location" sidebar works as a tab element, but I can't find a way to get the widgets and manipulate the result as I want and be able to create my own sidebar html.

Also if the user adds the new **Gallery Widget** the result must look as the image above.

Do you think that using sidebars and widgets is the best option? Do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Technically "off topic" here as your actual question is open-ended and there is lots of room for opinion.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Sidebars and widgets are a perfect way to organize these elements.  Keep in mind these are simply tools to organize blocks for repeated use in various locations.

So, officially, my answers to your two questions are:

Yes.  No.